# Access DatabaseContext after Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have created a basic `DatabaseContext` which handles the communication with a SQLite-Database:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GearComponent> GearComponents{ get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext() { }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename = database.db");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<GearComponent>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I registered this `DatabaseContext` in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Filename=database.db"));
```

I created a database with this command:

> dotnet ef migrations add testMigration

I also auto-created a controller to access the database via HTTP-GET/POST/PUT.

This controller gets an instance of the `DatabaseContext`:

```
public class GearComponentsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public GearComponentsController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //...
}
```

This `GearComponentsController` mainly is for the frontend to receive the database entries. For the backend I don't want to go with HTTP-POST/GET etc. but instead I want to directly access the `DatabaseContext` - but how?

I tried this in `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            db.GearComponents.Add(new GearComponent("Text", "Descr.", "08.12.2018"));
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

But my `database.db` never receives this entry.

**Edit: For everyone who is interested in how I got around this, look** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683593/asp-net-core-calling-controller-http-endpoints-always-leads-to-bad-request).

Comment: Your `This GearComponentsController mainly is for the frontend to receive the database entries. For the backend I don't want to go with HTTP-POST/GET etc. but instead I want to directly access the DatabaseContext - but how?` these line are not clear! Would you further explain me please!

Comment: `GearComponentsController` was auto-generated from VisualStudio and only contains HTTP endpoints for inserting / getting `GearComponent`-Objects from the `DatabseContext`. I don't want to go this way in my backend (sending HTTP-requests) but I want to directly access the `DatabaseContext` (like I have shown in my last code excerpt

Comment: Okay! I have checked! First problem is that you have placed your code in wrong place! it wouldn't even execute when the application start.

Comment: So how can I fix that. Could you describe what is wrong with my code in a little bit more detail, please?

Comment: First tell me why do you need to insert value into database just after the application start?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Not directly after but while the application is running

Comment: It is really unclear what you want to achieve, but from what you already mentioned it seems, that you want to access `DatabaseContext` outside your controller somewhere on the backend and perform some business logic and you don´t know how ?

Comment: @Nashmár Exactly! Or if that's not working (it looks like it doesn't) - what would be best practice to do that? I just want to insert something into my database while my app is running! Please, that's very basic functionality

Comment: @binaryBigInt See my answer

Comment: Where in your code do you want to access the database and how do you think it should be triggered? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

As in the docs described, the method CreateWebhostbuilder is used to differ between build host and run host.
To run the host means, the code after is as reachable as after a throw statement.
Try this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //use var host to build the host
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            db.GearComponents.Add(new GearComponent("Text", "Descr.", "08.12.2018"));
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Run host after seeding
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Edit:
As far as I understand your issue now, you have a frontend, which should only consume the content of the database, if the refresh-button is clicked.
Along with that, your backend should consume other webservices and insert the consumed gearcomponents into the database.
In cause of the fact, that you don’t want another application do that job, which could be a windows-service (easy to handle intervals for updating the database),
the only way to trigger the Updates is to start them from the GearComponentsController or in an actionFilter. This way you can update your database and provide the data to the frontend. I hope, performance doesn’t matter.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I want to update the database while my website is running. I don't see that working with your approach

Comment: @binaryBigInt When/Where/How do you want to update your database? This is not clearly asked. When you want to access the database from another application, I‘d recommend to source out the Context from your Webapplication to a class-library and use this for a console-app (for example).

Comment: I don't want to access the database from another application. I just want to access it from my backend without going through sending HTTP Post stuff. My C# ASP.NET backend will access different webservices and store the results from those webservices in this database. There is a "refresh"-Button at the frontend which reloads all database entries and displays them in a HTML-table.

Comment: And how do you think the frontend communicates with the backend, if not with http?

Comment: @binaryBigInt I edited my answer hoping I understand your needs now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to work with `DatabaseContext` outside your controller to perform some business logic. You can use straightforward approach with [repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design). Will simply demonstrate for inserting data. Assuming you have model `GearComponent` created and EntityFramework already seted up.

Create file which contains interface and class which implements this interface:

```
public interface IGearComponentRepository
{
  void Create(GearComponent obj)
}

public class GearComponentRepository : IGearComponentRepository
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    public GearComponentRepository (DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   public void Create(GearComponent data)
   {
      _context.Add(data);
      _context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

You need to register this service via IoC container in you `Startup.cs` file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
..
     services.AddMvc();
     services.AddTransient<IGearComponentRepository, GearComponentRepository>();
..
}
```

Then you can use Repositories from your Controller

```
public class GearComponentsController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly IGearComponentRepository _gearComponentRepository;

public GearComponentsController(IGearComponentRepository 
_gearComponentRepository)
{
  _gearComponentRepository = gearComponentRepository;
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(GearComponent data)
{
    _dataRepository.Create(data);

    return Ok();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hostBuilder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args);
            var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(env) && env.Equals("Production"))
            {
                hostBuilder.ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
                {
                    // Read GelfLoggerOptions from appsettings.json
                    builder.Services.Configure<GelfLoggerOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection("Graylog"));

                    // Optionally configure GelfLoggerOptions further.
                    builder.Services.PostConfigure<GelfLoggerOptions>(options =>
                        options.AdditionalFields["machine_name"] = Environment.MachineName);

                    // Read Logging settings from appsettings.json and add providers.
                    builder.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                        .AddConsole()
                        //.AddDebug()
                        .AddGelf();
                });
            }

            var host = hostBuilder.Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Retrieve your DbContext isntance here
                    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<NozomiDbContext>();

                    if (env != null && !env.Equals("Production"))
                    {
                        dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dbContext.Database.SetCommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds);
                        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
                    }
                    // place your DB seeding code here
                    //DbSeeder.Seed(dbContext);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex); 
                    // Continue
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }
```

Focusing on:

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
```

and

```
var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<NozomiDbContext>();
```

You will be able to access your dbContext just like that.